Best practice for new module
I have a question on how to organise my project, currently, everything is in Python.
The workspace is composed of several packages, with a main one from which the launch file is called. Then, this launch file will call the main node of the main package, and launch files from the other packages. Something like this:
src/
├── package_A
│   └── ...
├── package_B
│   ├── package_B
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── node.py
│   ├── config
│   ├── launch
│   │   └── pkgB.launch.py
│   ├── package.xml
│   ├── resource
│   │   └── package_B
│   ├── setup.cfg
│   └── setup.py
├── MAIN_PACKAGE
│   ├── config
│   ├── launch
│   │   └── main.launch.py  // Entry point of my project
│   ├── package.xml
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── resource
│   │   └── MAIN_PACKAGE
│   ├── MAIN_PACKAGE
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── main_node.py
│   ├── setup.cfg
│   └── setup.py
└── package_Z
    ├── ...

But now, I want to create a "library", a set of classes to use as a tool. Those classes would have nothing to do with ROS (they are not a Node). They will be used from the main_node.py to rationalise some computations.
What is the best way to integrate them into my project?

Create a new package and import it into my main package (even if there will be no Node or launch file to call a Node).
Create a new module inside my project (i.e. a new folder next to MAIN_PACKAGE/MAIN_PACKAGE, like MAIN_PACKAGE/MyLib).
Create a submodule (i.e. a new folder inside MAIN_PACKAGE/MAIN_PACKAGE, like MAIN_PACKAGE/MAIN_PACKAGE/MyLib).
Keep everything inside MAIN_PACKAGE/MAIN_PACKAGE, even if it will become messy.

Thanks in advance.

First of all, you shouldn't use upper case letters on your package names.
EDITED:
I think you should add them as submodules.
your_package
 |
 +-- your_package
      |
      +-- __init__.py
      |
      +-- main_node.py
      |
      +-- submodules
           |
           +-- __init__.py
           |
           +-- submodule1.py

But if you are going to use them as nodes, I think you should put them in the same folder where your main node is located.

Yeah, I don't use capital. Actually, it was just for this question, to emphasise it in the tree. But thanks for the tip, I didn't know it was forbidden/not recommended.

You're welcome, but you should take other people opinions too because I didn't work on ROS2 with Python, I use C++. It was just my opinion...

Thanks for the answer. I will wait for the other person's answer to see if it makes a consensus. It was my favourite option (but also with the folder next to the main folder).

Agree since you stated "They will be used from the main_node.py" ... but if there is a possibility of any other node needing them in the future, answer is different - same concept as where to define custom messages/services/actions - separate package usually.
